# How do I add custom icon to Place Name AR.JS

Tags: ar.js

How do we replace the Place icon with a `PNG image` in the `AR.js` library? I have read the article and I think we can use a `PNG image` to display as a place icon but we can't do it with the place names.

According to the article, this is how we display places' names and using their default icon.

```
// add place name
                    const text = document.createElement('a-link');
                    text.setAttribute('gps-entity-place', `latitude: ${latitude}; longitude: ${longitude};`);
                    text.setAttribute('title', place.name);
                    text.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.example.com/');
                    text.setAttribute('scale', '13 13 13');

                    text.addEventListener('loaded', () => {
                        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('gps-entity-place-loaded'))
                    });
```

This is how we use a custom image.

```
 const icon = document.createElement('a-image');
                    icon.setAttribute('gps-entity-place', `latitude: ${latitude}; longitude: ${longitude};`);
                    icon.setAttribute('name', place.name);
                    icon.setAttribute('src', '../assets/map-marker.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>The property gps-entity-place is read only. This means that you cannot use setAttribute to modify it.</s>

So my previous answer didn't completely answer the question. Looking deeper into AFrame documentation, I found that it is possible to have gps-projected-entity-place spawned with new entities. However, it needs to be done as outline here: https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/location-based-tutorial/#introducing-javascript-with-arjs

This would mean you should be doing:
`text.setAttribute('gps-projected-entity-place', { latitude: ${latitude}, longitude: ${longitude} });`